# How can I see all log4j2 output generated during junit5 tests run with the Ant junitlauncher and junitreport tasks?

Tags: java, junit, ant, log4j2, junit5

I'm running a number of test classes which use a mix of `System.out.println(...)` and Log4j2 `log.info(...)` logging. I can see all the logs in the HTML report for the first test class to run, but subsequent tests only seem to retain direct uses of `System.out.println(...)`. How can I preserve all the logs in the report?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ensure you're running a version of Ant greater than 1.10.5 - there are a number of patches for the junit components in newer Ant releases.

Secondly, enable the `follow` option in the log4j appender. Sample log4j configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true" ignoreExceptions="false">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601}{UTC} %c: %m %ex%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="DEBUG">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```